# Windows 10 Freeze

Tags: windows, windows-10, freeze

I upgraded my Windows 8 to Windows 10, 8 months ago and lately I've been noticing that the Laptop at first becomes slow and freezes for no apparent reason. I've tried opening task manager(Ctrl + Alt + Del) but it does not allow me to do that. After I wait it out, it comes to that Ctrl + Alt + Del screen and when i select "Task Manager" it opens and freezes along, like the rest. I've been noticing this for the past two weeks.

I mainly suspect two facts here. The first suspicion is my Avira Antivirus. Four of them keep running in the background and are among the top in slowing down the laptop. My second suspicion is the memory. Only 122 GB is free. Please help 'cuz this thing is really getting into my nerves.

```
OS Name Microsoft Windows 10 Home
Version 10.0.14393 Build 14393
Other OS Description    Not Available
OS Manufacturer Microsoft Corporation
System Name DESKTOP-QJT7O3V
System Manufacturer Sony Corporation
System Model    SVE17127CXB
System Type x64-based PC
System SKU  54510764
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3632QM CPU @ 2.20GHz, 2200 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)
BIOS Version/Date   Insyde Corp. R0140D6, 8/23/2012
SMBIOS Version  2.7
Embedded Controller Version 1.40
BIOS Mode   Legacy
BaseBoard Manufacturer  Sony Corporation
BaseBoard Model Not Available
BaseBoard Name  Base Board
Platform Role   Mobile
Secure Boot State   Unsupported
PCR7 Configuration  Binding Not Possible
Windows Directory   C:\WINDOWS
System Directory    C:\WINDOWS\system32
Boot Device \Device\HarddiskVolume1
Locale  United States
Hardware Abstraction Layer  Version = "10.0.14393.206"
User Name   DESKTOP-QJT7O3V\Jeff
Time Zone   India Standard Time
Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 8.00 GB
Total Physical Memory   7.95 GB
Available Physical Memory   5.49 GB
Total Virtual Memory    9.20 GB
Available Virtual Memory    6.45 GB
Page File Space 1.25 GB
Page File   C:\pagefile.sys
Hyper-V - VM Monitor Mode Extensions    Yes
Hyper-V - Second Level Address Translation Extensions   Yes
Hyper-V - Virtualization Enabled in Firmware    No
Hyper-V - Data Execution Protection Yes
```

[image: Task Manager Screenshot]

Comment: There's nothing indicating freezes just due to high CPU load. When it freezes, try using caps lock or num lock. Does the indicator light change? If it doesn't, everything is stuck at a kernel level.

Did you check the Event Logs/Viewer for any hints? Can you check the S.M.A.R.T. statistics of your hard drive?

Comment: Edit your question and system configuration.

Comment: It got stuck again now, in the task manager it showed 100% disk but all running processes were 0. Why is this happening??

Comment: Try hard disk diagnostic once.